# Oracle table lock is not working

Tags: java, oracle, locking

I have a springframework scheduling service that executes this code every minute on two different servers. As the comment indicates, I assumed that the first server to get the lock will continue processing, and the second server will attempt to set the lock and get an ORA-00054 error then exit (return).  This is not happening and both server logs have the “JPB** continue processing” line.

It was suggested that it could be the timing so that the first server finishes processing before the second server tries to set the lock.  I know this is not happening because part of the processing is to delete the records in MY_TABLE.  Even if the second server sets the lock after the first server was done processing, it would have no records to process.  I have additional log statements (not shown below) that tell me both servers are processing the same records.

Am I not setting the lock correctly?

Thank you for your assistance.

```
    // Because the same timer event will be running on both production servers and calling
    // this method, a lock must be set on the table so that the first method that gets 
    // the lock can process, and the other will exit.
    String executeStatement = "LOCK TABLE MY_TABLE IN EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT";
    try {
        Statement statement = idbConn.createStatement();
        statement.execute(executeStatement);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // If the error is ORA-00054: resource busy, then the other server locked the table first
        // and will process the records in the table, so just return.
        if (e.getMessage().contains("ORA-00054")) {
            ora00054 = true;
            logger.debug("JPB** Trapped the ORA-00054 error setting the LOCK on the MY_TABLE table ");
        } else {
            otherException = true;
            logger.error("A non-busy error occurred executing LOCK on MY_TABLE table ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } finally {
        if (ora00054 || otherException) {
            // Close connection
            logger.debug("JPB** exiting");
            return;
        }
    }
    logger.debug("JPB** continue processing");
    // Select and process the records in MY_TABLE, delete them, then commit to save and release the lock.
```

Comment: Hi, could you check on DB side if there are any locks after you execute your java code? 

SELECT * FROM v$lock
JOIN dba_objects
ON v$lock.ID1=dba_objects.object_id
and object_name='MY_TABLE';

Also, you should close your connection in finally block

Comment: Do you turn off autocommit for your connection?

Comment: Thank you nomadus. I use the connection in later processing and close it in code not shown above.

Comment: I cut out the close connection code in the snippet above to simplify the display.

Comment: Thank you mustaccio!  I set autocommit to false and it is working!